# Android Studio can't open file explorer to choose project destination

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2.1.3.
I can't open file exploper in Android Studio to choose destination of my existing project. **Nothing to show**...
[Nothing to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMQYG.png)

It works on my desktop PC (Windows 10). It takes ***about a second*** to show directories.
Notebook has Windows 10 too, but something goes wrong. "Nothing to show" ***even after an hour***.

How can I fix this problem? Is it possible to find any solution?